# ASP.NET label does not wrap in older browsers

Tags: word-wrap

browser would be mozilla firefox 5

if the text is:
text is too longggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg

I would like it to be wrapped:

```
text is too longggggggggggggg
ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the CSS style [`word-wrap: break-word`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap)

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a multiline TextBox.

Comment: tried everything in here http://forums.asp.net/t/1614815.aspx/1  If i used textbox multiline, no matter how I change the text font it is always standard.

Comment: Did you try Literal.Text too?

Comment: Set a Width to the label and it should wrap.  It worked in FF 5.0.1 as such:  http://browsershots.org/screenshots/77319252eba87c5882460dd86debe784

Comment: tried literal.text too, there is no way i can make it wrap, word-wrap:break-word and those css do not work

Comment: can't use a multiline textbox as user can modify the textbox from disabled="false" to true and try to send something

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to specify the width of your label. In my case I put it inside the  and add this css class:  display: inline-block; width:123px;word-break:break-all;